# Connect to Windows app with WebRequest

Tags: c#, webrequest

Is it possible for a windows mobile phone to use WebRequest to connect to a windows client application. I mean an actual windows forms application.
I want to use webrequest but the client application cannot be a web app or anything, it has to be a windows forms program. So, is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible, yes. Easy, or a good idea for that matter, no.

If your WinForms app also opens up a Socket and listens for requests on port 80.

Essentially you have to build a web server into your WinForms application and then deal with firewall and security issues of the traffic getting from the Mobile Phone to the computer running your application.

Comment: If anyone happens to be wondering, it isnt actually that hard. You just use a socket to receive the requests and handle the headers and stuff :)